# I would like to change only clicked header link text color with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started to learn to code recently and to create my portfolio. I am working on the header and I would like to change the text color header link tag when it is only clicked once.
When I clicked the link, the text color changed to red and when I clicked the link now but when I click another link, the previous link is still red.

[image]

I would like to change the text color back from red to gray when I click another.
**Example:-** OK - home **about** work skill contact  NO - **home** about **work** skill contact

**Header.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link as ScrollLink } from "react-scroll";

const Header = (props) => {
  const { headerPage } = props;
  const [onClickChangeColor, setOnClickChangeColor] = useState(false);
  const redText = () => {
    setOnClickChangeColor(!onClickChangeColor);
  };

  return (
    <div class="mr-8 cursor-pointer">
      <ScrollLink
        className={onClickChangeColor ? "text-[#FF5757]" : ""}
        onClick={redText}
        to={headerPage}
        smooth={true}
        duration={500}
      >
        {headerPage}
      </ScrollLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

**HeaderLayout.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";

const HeaderLayout = () => {
  const headerPages = ["home", "about", "work", "skill", "contact"];

  return (
    <div class="sticky top-0 flex justify-end h-20 text-md pt-10 mr-10 text-center bg-[#292929]">
      {headerPages.map((headerPage) => (
        <Header headerPage={headerPage}>{headerPage}</Header>
      ))}

      <div
        className="resume"
        class="w-24 h-8  text-[#FF5757] border border-[#FF5757] rounded-md"
      >
        <a
          href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/usp=sharing"
          class="block"
        >
          resume
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeaderLayout;
```

I am using React and Tailwind. English is my second language and I hope everyone understands what I want to do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the color handling state to parent (Header Layout)

```
const HeaderLayout = () => {
  const headerPages = ["home", "about", "work", "skill", "contact"];
  const [selectedHeader, changeSelectedHeader] = useState("");

  return (
    <div class="sticky top-0 flex justify-end h-20 text-md pt-10 mr-10 text-center bg-[#292929]">
      {headerPages.map((headerPage) => (
        <Header
          headerPage={headerPage}
          changeSelectedHeader={changeSelectedHeader}
          selectedHeader={selectedHeader}
        >
          {headerPage}
        </Header>
      ))}
```

then, make the child like this

```
import React from "react";
import { Link as ScrollLink } from "react-scroll";

const Header = (props) => {
  const { headerPage, changeSelectedHeader, selectedHeader } = props;
  const redText = () => {
    changeSelectedHeader(headerPage);
  };
  return (
    <div class="mr-8 cursor-pointer">
      <ScrollLink
        className={headerPage === selectedHeader ? "text-[#FF5757]" : ""}
        onClick={redText}
        to={headerPage}
        smooth={true}
        duration={500}
      >
        {headerPage}
      </ScrollLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the selected item index in the `HeaderLayout` component and then use it to decide the header item color depending on that.

1. Add another state to maintain the selected header item state in `HeaderLayout`.

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(-1);
```

2. Provide the `headerIndex`, `selectedIndex`, and `setSelectedIndex` as props to the `Header` compoenent.

```
{headerPages.map((headerPage, headerIndex) => (
  <Header
    headerPage={headerPage}
    setSelectedIndex={setSelectedIndex}
    selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
    headerIndex={headerIndex}
  >
    {headerPage}
  </Header>
))}
```

3. In the `Header` component get the props and set the header item CSS as below.

```
const { headerPage, selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex, headerIndex } = props;
...
...
<ScrollLink
  className={headerIndex === selectedIndex ? "text-[#FF5757]" : ""}
  onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(headerIndex)}
  to={headerPage}
  smooth={true}
  duration={500}
>
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit headless-night-nfvg5l]